# Gatsby - ERROR #98123 WEBPACK I cant build my app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby

So I couldn't build my gatsby app because it has quite a lot of dependencies on window. Many components are built depending on the width of the browser window.
After the "gatsby build" command I got WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined.
I found a solution on the internet to paste the following code into gatsby-node.js:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
if (stage === 'build-html' || stage === 'develop-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /node_modules/,
                    use: loaders.null(),
                },
            ],
         },
     });
   }
};
```

but when rebuilding the app I get this error:

```
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Skipped not serializable cache item 'Compilation/modules|json|C:\Users\Damian\Documents\Ossolinsky\app\node_modules\null-loader\dist\cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[13].use!C:\Users\Damian\Documents\Ossolinsky\app\node_modules\gatsby\package.json': No serializer registered for JSONParseError

 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating SSR bundle failed

Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing empty string

File: node_modules\gatsby\package.json

not finished Building HTML renderer - 1.257s
```

Answer (score 0):

> I found a solution on the internet to paste the following code into
> gatsby-node.js

This is the recipe of the devil. With the following snippet:

```
{
    test: /node_modules/,
    use: loaders.null(),
},
```

You are adding a null loader to all `node_modules` folder and the idea here is to add **only** instances that need to be ignored in the server because they had a `window` dependency. Since rules is an array you can do:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
if (stage === 'build-html' || stage === 'develop-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /some_package_1/,
                    use: loaders.null(),
                },
                {
                    test: /some_package_2/,
                    use: loaders.null(),
                },
                {
                    test: /some_package_3/,
                    use: loaders.null(),
                },
            ],
         },
     });
   }
};
```

Keep in mind that `/some_package_3/` is a regular expression (hence the `test` key and that's why is between slashes) that needs to match the folder name inside `node_modules`.

To know which string should be placed as a regular expression, normally if you `import { some_package_1 } from 'some_package_1'` means that `some_package_1` is the folder inside `node_modules` that needs to be added.

There's a chance that `some_package_1` is not using a `window` *per se*, and it's a dependency of the dependency: in that case, you need to find out which one is it and apply the same reasoning ignoring it.

> Many components are built depending on the width of the browser
> window.

If those are internal components, you should check first if there's a window available when the component is being rendered/parsed, as the [docs suggests](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/), with the following condition:

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    return <div>Component that can use window and will bypass SSR</div>
  }

  return <div>Component that can't use window</div>
}
```